# Set referenced DLL path at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, dynamic, load, runtime

Is it possible to change the path of a DLL at runtime? I need to link a DLL, but I will not be able to give the DLL to the user, but i know the user have that DLL on it's hard disk. So i have show a generic form to the user, where it can enter the path, then I have to take that path (as string) and load the dll dynamically to my program. After it's loaded I will use stuff from that DLL.

Is this possible and even if, how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Chris' answer.

To avoid using reflection on the loaded assembly, code your classes within the assembly against common interfaces and you can then instantiate your objects like so:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(pathOfAssembly);
InterfaceName instance = (InterfaceName)assembly.CreateInstance("fully qualified type name", true);
```

Comment: If I dont have the DLL reference in the project, it wont compile! And when I add the reference, but the DLL ist not located at the EXE is, I get an Exeption just before Main() is called!

Comment: You would need to store your interface in an assembly common to both the DLL you are loading dynamically and the application loading the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You can load an assembly or dll dynamically from path using `Assembly.LoadFile(pathOfAssembly)` method. Once it is loaded you can create instances of classes it contains and call methods.